# Passing a method down two levels

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple little game for fun, but I'm hitting a stump when it comes to passing this method down to its grandchildren. I've found similar topics, but none that answered my question. For this question, I've managed to narrow the code down to what the problem is perceived to be.

The relevant component structure is `App.js > Runeboard.js > Rune.js`

**The Goal:** To have Rune.js have an `onClick` function on each rune that is dynamically produced by whatever is in `this.state.usersRunes`.

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the function itself, or passing it down as props, because console logging the runes values all succeed when in Runeboard.js, and even in Rune.

This works, but is not dynamic to what is in the `this.state.usersRunes` array:

```
      return (
            <div>
                Runeboard
                <span onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.usersRunes[0])}> {this.props.usersRunes[0]} </span>
                <span onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.usersRunes[1])}> {this.props.usersRunes[1]} </span>
                <span onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.usersRunes[2])}> {this.props.usersRunes[2]} </span>
                <span onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.usersRunes[3])}> {this.props.usersRunes[3]} </span>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
```

The problem with that, is I'd like for every item in `this.state.usersRunes` (an array of integers), a Rune component that has its own `onClick` that successfuly executes `activateRune` with its parameter of the value of the rune. (The value of the rune being `this.state.usersRunes` So `this.state.usersRunes = [2,3,5,9]` the values would be 2, 3, 5, and 9.

---

So even though the above works, this does not and I do not understand why:

**App.js**
The activateRune function:

```
    activateRune(rune) {
        if (this.state.inBet || this.state.mustBet) {
            this.call(rune)
        } else if (!this.state.inBet) {
            this.setMessage("You cannot place a rune first!")
        }
    }
```

App.js render:

```
                <Runeboard
                    activateRune={this.activateRune}
                    usersRunes={this.state.usersRunes}
                />
```

**Runeboard.js**
render:

```
        let rune = this.props.usersRunes.map((rune, i) => {
            console.log(rune) // this works and successfully prints the array's integers
            return(
                <div>
                    <Rune activateRune={this.props.activateRune} 
runeValue={rune} key={i} />
                </div>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {rune}
            </div>
        )
```

**Rune.js**
render:

```
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.runeValue)}>
                {this.props.runeValue} // this works and successfully displays the value
            </div>
        );
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'this.call(rune)' in activateRune(). The 'this' here might not be the function itself.

Comment: @haopeng this.call(rune) is just activating another function, called "call(rune)" in App. The parameter 'rune' is just tossing the value in given from activateRune(rune)

Comment: In your Rune.js, there's a () => this.props.activateRune(this.props.runeValue), but you didn't pass down the activateRune() in your Runeboard.js render.

Comment: @haopeng Added `<Rune activateRune={this.props.activateRune} runeValue={rune} key={i} />` there, does not work. Than you though! I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutout to @xiiishaneiiix and @haopeng for the fast answers! Their comments/answer helped me try out some new things, which made me test some things and narrow what the cause was.

Turns out it was within Runeboard, in a conflict with the parameter and variable name being the same.

```
        let rune = this.props.usersRunes.map((rune, i) => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Rune activateRune={this.props.activateRune} runeValue={rune} key={i} />
                </div>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {rune}
            </div>
        )
```

Having the same name, the property I was trying to pass was actually grabbing the variable with the same name, and not the parameter from map.

The solution was in renaming the variable and parameter, clearing telling the code that we want the parameter from the `map` and not the variable:

```
        let runes = this.props.usersRunes.map((runeValue, i) => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Rune activateRune={this.props.activateRune} runeValue={runeValue} key={i} />
                </div>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {runes}
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: And you  should put the `key` in the `div`  instead of in `<Rune />`

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be an issue with your syntax.

`<div onClick={() => {this.props.activateRune(rune)}}>`

If you use curly braces, `{}`, you need a return value:

`<div onClick={() => {return this.props.activateRune(rune)}}>`

You can also avoid the curly braces and have it be:

`<div onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(rune)}>`

Comment: imho, it's not necessary to return value in () => {}. it's just a syntax sugar to skip the curly braces & 'return' for quick return, e.g. () => 'a'.

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately it did not work, throwing no error.
Tried: 
`<div onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(this.props.runeValue)}>` and
`<div onClick={() => {return this.props.activateRune(this.props.runeValue)}}>`

Runeboard.js as well, with 
```
<div onClick={() => this.props.activateRune(rune)} >
                    <Rune activateRune={this.props.activateRune} runeValue={rune} key={i} />
                </div>
```

Comment: Great idea @xiishaneiiix ! Unfortunately it did not work, throwing no error. I tried doing that both in Rune and Runeboard. Sorry for previous comment's disaster of syntax, haha.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help! I'm not sure what's going on - any way we can see the full code?

Comment: No problem! Your comment made me think about it and try something, which was actually the problem.

The map parameter wasn't actually being called, instead calling the variable above with the same name. Thank you!!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you were able to figure it out.